# Maximum depth of fields in a map or array? Usage limit question

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My question is related to the Google Cloud Firestore documentation listed here:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions

Specifically, this line:
"Maximum depth of fields in a map or array  20"

Does this mean an array can have a maximum length of 20? I am unfamiliar with the term "depth of fields".

If this is the wrong stack website to ask question, please send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's referring to nested objects.  A map type field can have nested maps with more fields.  You can refer to those nested fields using dot syntax.

```
mapField: {
    nestedMapField: {
        a: 1
    }
}
```

To use `a` in a query, you would refer to it like this: `mapField.nestedMapField.a`.  The maximum amount of nesting like this 20 "deep".

Comment: Thanks Doug. Shameless plug, your videos on promises for google cloud functions helped me a ton.